# CakePHP: Unknown column with saveMany

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have the following array that I'm trying to save to the database..

```
$this->ProgramApplication->saveMany($priApps);  

$priApps:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ProgramCurrentResidence] => Array
                (
                    [program_id] => 3698076220130520
                    [customer_id] => jraer4081
                    [residence_duration] => 61-90-days
                    [residence_stability] => renting-leasing
                    [payment_current] => yes
                    [payment_amount_past_due] => 
                    [landlord_name] => Blake Woods
                    [landlord_phone] => (269)777-7777
                    [landlord_fax] => 
                    [notes] => 
                )


            [ProgramPreviousResidence] => Array
                (
                    [program_id] => 3698076220130520
                    [customer_id] => jrayner4081
                    [residence_duration] => 1year 
                    [street_address] => 1637 Colfax Ave
                    [city] => The Harbor
                    [state] => me
                    [zip] => 49022
                )
            )

    )
```

That keeps throwing the following error...

Database Error
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ProgramCurrentResidence.program_id' in 'where clause'

SQL Query: SELECT `ProgramApplication`.`program_id`, `ProgramApplication`.`customer_id`, `ProgramApplication`.`secondary_customer_id`, `ProgramApplication`.`secondary_customer_relationship`, `ProgramApplication`.`sales_associate`, `ProgramApplication`.`store`, `ProgramApplication`.`created_on`, `ProgramApplication`.`date_submitted`, `ProgramApplication`.`date_delivered`, `ProgramApplication`.`stock_number`, `ProgramApplication`.`deal_status`, `ProgramApplication`.`deal_status_conditional_reasoning`, `ProgramApplication`.`transfered_to_dealpack`, `ProgramApplication`.`presubmittal_notes`, `ProgramApplication`.`underwriters_notes`, `ProgramApplication`.`modified_by` FROM `expreta2_x12`.`programs` AS `ProgramApplication` WHERE ((`ProgramCurrentResidence`.`program_id` = '3698076220130520') AND (`ProgramCurrentResidence`.`customer_id` = 'jrayner4081')) LIMIT 1

Here's my model for ProgramCurrentResidence...

```
<?php
class ProgramCurrentResidence extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'program_current_residences';

    public $primaryKey = 'program_id';

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'ProgramApplication' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'program_id'
            )
        );

}
?>
```

A bit a code from the Program Application Model

```
    <?php

class ProgramApplication extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'programs';
    public $primaryKey = 'program_id';

    public $actAs = array('Containable');

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Inventory' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'stock_number'
        ),
        'Customer' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'customer_id'
        ),
        'Employee' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'sales_associate'
        ),
        'CustomerPersonalInformation' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'customer_id'
        ),
        'CustomerContactInformation' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'customer_id'
        ),
        'CustomerMarketingOption' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'customer_id'
        )
    );


    public $hasOne = array(
        'Desklog' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'program_id'
        ),
        'Funding' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'program_id'
        ),
        'ProgramCurrentResidence' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'program_id'
        ),
        'ProgramPreviousResidence' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'program_id'
        ),
        'ProgramCurrentEmployment' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'program_id'
        ),
        'ProgramPreviousEmployment' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'program_id'
        ),
        'ProgramIncome' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'program_id'
        ),
        'ProgramReference' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'program_id'
        ),
        'ProgramAdditionalInformation' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'program_id'
        ),
        'ProgramDoublePreviousEmployment'=> array(
            'foreignKey' => 'program_id'
        ),
        'ProgramDoublePreviousResidence'=> array(
            'foreignKey' => 'program_id'
        ),
        'ProgramExpense'=> array(
            'foreignKey' => 'program_id'
        ),
        'ProgramVerificationWorksheet'=> array(
            'foreignKey' => 'program_id'
        )
    );

}

?>
```

This could be the contain your talking about..

```
// Get all the data corrosponding to the secondary customer
                $secondaryRow = $this->Customer->find('all', array(
                    'conditions' => array("Customer.customer_id" => $secondary),
                    'contain' => array(
                        'CustomerPersonalInformation',
                        'CustomerContactInformation',
                        'CustomerMarketingOption',
                        'ProgramApplication' => array(
                            'ProgramCurrentResidence',
                            'ProgramPreviousResidence',
                            'ProgramCurrentEmployment',
                            'ProgramPreviousEmployment',
                            'ProgramIncome',
                            'ProgramAdditionalInformation',
                            'ProgramDoublePreviousEmployment',
                            'ProgramDoublePreviousResidence',
                            'ProgramExpense',
                            'ProgramVerificationWorksheet'
                        ),
                        'CustomerInteraction'
                    ),
                ));
```

I know the table contains every field that is used but for some reason it continues to spit out this error? I'm assuming its the model but I could be wrong.

Comment: looks like the data is getting selected from expreta2_x12 table which is not joined to ProgramCurrentResidence

Comment: expreta2_x12 is the Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are doing a find on ProgramApplication and the model from ProgramApplication doens't have a relationship to ProgramCurrentResidence. **You might need to add a hasOne or hasMany of ProgramCurrentResidence to ProgramApplication model.**

Comment: Added the code from program application model. Does it look correct or do I need to add a hasMany?

Comment: @Subie could you post your whole ProgramApplication model? Because from what you showed me it seems like that should work, and the problem might be some other query...Do you have a 'contain' on a find somewhere above?

Comment: We do have a contain. I have posted above.

Comment: @Subie sorry I never got back, did you figure out your issue?

Comment: Happened to be with the array. Your answer help solve it so thank you.